# jQuery Mobile CSS breaks button click events

Tags: jquery, html, clojure, jquery-mobile-button

I am writing a mobile web-page using Clojure and jQuery mobile. Everything on the site works fine when I have the link for jquery mobile CSS commented out, but when I have this style sheet enabled, none of my buttons work and no errors are visible. I am sure I am missing something simple as this is the first mobile page I have written and I am new to web development.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/> -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- <body> -->
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Conwat's Game of Life</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="itr-div" height=100 width=100></div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <canvas data-role="canvas" id="surface" height=400 width=400>
      </canvas>
      <form id="options-form" name="options-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <button data-role="button" type="button" class="button" id="pause-btn" value="Pause/Resume">
      </button>
      <button data-role="button" type="button" class="button" id="clear-btn" value="Clear">
      </button>
      <button data-role="button" type="button" class="button" id="heatmap-btn" value="Toggle Heatmap">
      </button>
        <!-- <input data-role="button" type="button" class="button" id="pause-btn" value="Pause/Resume">
      <input data-role="button" type="button" class="button" id="clear-btn" value="Clear">
      <input data-role="button" type="button" class="button" id="heatmap-btn" value="Toggle Heatmap"> -->

      </form>

<div data-role="footer">
  This is a footer
</div>
</html>
```

Clojure:

```
;onclick listeners
(set-onclick! (by-id "pause-btn") #(swap! paused not)
              (println "set on click pause called"))

(set-onclick! (by-id "heatmap-btn") #(swap! show-heatmap not)
              (println "set on click heat called"))

(set-onclick! (by-id "clear-btn") #(do (swap! game-state clear-board)
                                       (swap! iteration (fn [itr] -1))
                                       (swap! game-heatmap empty-heatmap)
                                       (draw-game)
                                       (update-itr)))
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: There isn't any javascript to the buttons?

Comment: BTW, your like with canvas `<canvas data-role="canvas" id="surface" height=400 width=400>` doesn't have quotes around width and height attributes. It should be: `<canvas data-role="canvas" id="surface" height="400" width="400">`. The same goes for the div above it. Divs should have width and height in css not as attributes. `style="width:100px;height:100px;"`

Comment: I am using Clojure. I didn't include them because everything in my Clojure code works fine when the link to jQuery mobile is commented out. Here is where I am setting the onclick event

Comment: @user2138602 have you tried loading the page with the javascript console tool (chrome) or firebug (firefox) open? I would hazard a guess that some error condition in the javascript is stopping the rest of the code after that error from running. The info about that error is needed to solve this bug.

Comment: There are no errors in the console. However, I may be missing something as this is my first website. Everything works fine when I comment out the CSS link for jquery mobile.

Comment: I would compare the styles and classes that are assigned to the buttons both when the CSS file is included and when not. I just created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcZfx/1) with the HTML you posted and the buttons seem to work when the CSS is included.